# Angular resolver NOT returning any when the returned value is observable created with the .asObservable() function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am just trying to mock up my http calls with a simple BehaviorSubject and an Observable properties in my resolver service. I do not understand why the following is not working:

**schedule-administration.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScheduleAdministrationService implements OnInit, Resolve<Observable<SportType[]>> {
  private _sportTypesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<SportType[]>([]);
  sportTypes$: Observable<SportType[]> = this._sportTypesSubject.asObservable();  

  constructor(private leagueAdminService: LeagueAdministrationService) {}

  resolve(): Observable<SportType[]> | Observable<Observable<SportType[]>> | Promise<Observable<SportType[]>> {
    this._sportTypesSubject.next([...])
    return this.sportTypes$;    
  }
}
```

I thought that the resolve method is supposed to subscribe to the returned observable? When I manually do `this.sportTypes$.subscribe(v => console.log(v))` it correctly logs the values....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem by your construct is that you initially use a `BehaviorSubject`. 
The Angular Router expect the result of your Resolver to be completed before return data.
So Using `BehaviorSubject` assume that you have only one value at a time, but the value can always change.

To Make this work i think you can only take the first emitted response/value e.g using the `first` operator:

```
resolve(): Observable<SportType[]> | Observable<Observable<SportType[]>> | Promise<Observable<SportType[]>> {
    return this._sportTypesSubject.asObservable().pipe(first())    
}
```

According to the Angular documentation

> A data provider class can be used with the router to resolve data during navigation. The interface defines a resolve() method that will be invoked when the navigation starts. **The router will then wait for the data to be resolved before the route is finally activated.**

Comment: hmm interesting, but if I were to be using http.get() I would be retrieving a list of all of the SportTypes not just the first one, any idea how to make it work with all of them?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh it isn't taking the first item, but the first response

Comment: @Drenai yeah, definitely, I completely missed that part, since a single response is a an entire list at a time. So see that it works now using `return this._sportTypesSubject.asObservable().pipe(first<SportType[]>()) ` I had to specify the type. But I'm still a little hazy as to why it didnt work before. Any chance you can add a little more detail in the answer. Does resolver expect the observable that is returned to be completed and not to emit any more values? Sorry i just want to make sure I understand it.